# SQL Server Instance Version

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, installation

I'm working with a SQL Server with several instances. Four of my instances are at 10.50.2811.0 and the remaining two are at 10.50.1765.0

I've tried running SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 and CU 6 to get it updated but the installer wont run. I receive the error:

> To continue, select a feature to install. If all features are already selected, these features are installed.

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you have to install SP1 and then CU6 (as mentioned in my comment)

- 10.50.2811 ==> 2679367 Cumulative update package 6 (CU6) for SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1
- 10.50.1765 ==> 2489376 Cumulative update package 6 (CU6) for SQL Server 2008 R2 **note this is for RTM**

Comment: When we tried to install SP1, it get an error message. I thinks it's already installed.

Comment: Check the version - `select CAST(SUBSTRING(@@Version, charindex('SQL', @@version, 1), 30) AS VARCHAR(max)) + ' + ' 
        + CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('productlevel') AS VARCHAR(50)) + ' + (Build' + 
             CAST(SERVERPROPERTY('ProductVersion') AS VARCHAR(50)) + ')'  as  ProductVersion`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions on this. Our consulting vendor ended up figuring the problem the second time around.